# Why subclasses override virtual functions can not change parent class default function parameters?

Tags: c++

I read some code from a book,like this:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Father
{
public:
    virtual void test(int value=520)
    {
        cout<<"father:"<<value<<endl;
    }
};

class Son :public Father
{
public:
    virtual void test(int value=250)
    {
        cout<<"son:"<<value<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Son* son =new Son;
    son->test();
    Father* fson= son;
    fson->test();
}
```

The program output:

> son250
>
> son520

The book says, default parameters of virtual functions determined at compile.

My question is:
The default parameters of a virtual function Why not decide at runtime? Like virtual function itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makers of C and C++ didn't want to complicate the matter. It is simple to implement default parameters resolved in compile time, and not so simple in run time. There is a workaround that you can and should use, however. Instead of using default parameter introduce one more virtual function that has no parameter.

```
class Father
{
public:
    virtual void test(int value)
    {
        cout << "father:" << value << endl;
    }


    virtual void test()
    {
        test(520);
    }
};

class Son : public Father
{
public:
    virtual void test(int value)
    {
        cout << "son:" << value << endl;
    }

    virtual void test()
    {
        test(250);
    }
};
```

Comment: I feel no need to complicate the language for this function now.